Turning a table from the web page into a data.frame
I am looking for a solution to scrap the data table from the web page u (see details below) into a data frame. My code is quite short as I am in pain to figure it out how to get the very table out of w:
library(rvest)

u <- paste0("https://www.frbservices.org/resources/financial-services/securities/",
            "volume-value-stats/quarterly-stats.html")

w <- read_html(u)


Other than Jan's answer, the documentation is helpful also https://rvest.tidyverse.org/

w |> 
  html_element("table") |> 
  html_table()

Yields:
# A tibble: 128 × 9
   Quarter Transfers originated1\n   …¹ Quarterly volume gro…² Value of transfers o…³
   <chr>   <chr>                        <chr>                  <chr>                 
 1 2023:Q4 6,843,936                    6.6                    116,793,254           
 2 2023:Q3 6,418,535                    2.0                    111,273,018           
 3 2023:Q2 6,293,096                    1.3                    109,076,373           
 4 2023:Q1 6,213,620                    10.7                   97,327,236            
 5 2022:Q4 5,612,418                    2.4                    86,085,772            
 6 2022:Q3 5,481,321                    3.2                    87,175,922            
 7 2022:Q2 5,313,329                    2.3                    85,977,539            
 8 2022:Q1 5,193,156                    9.0                    82,567,500            
 9 2021:Q4 4,765,993                    5.5                    79,546,935            
10 2021:Q3 4,515,630                    (5.6)                  75,480,685            
# ℹ 118 more rows
# ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`Transfers originated1\n   (number)`,
#   ²​`Quarterly volume growth\n   (percent)`,
#   ³​`Value of transfers originated\n   ($millions)`
# ℹ 5 more variables: `Quarterly value growth\n   (percent)` <chr>,
#   `Average value per transfer\n   ($millions)` <dbl>,
#   `Average daily volume of transfers2\n   (number)` <chr>, …

